# Google Places API Autocomplete - keep placeholder in browser language even though results are listed in another language

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, multilingual

I'm using the Google Places API Autocomplete in a multilingual form.
I want to populate my fields in English so the address information goes into my database in English.  The easiest way to do this seems to be to add the "language" parameter to the API and set the language to English. The problem is that if I do that, then even on my French or Spanish form, the built-in placeholder that Google puts in my input field is also in English.

I could also not set the language to English and have the fields filled in in another language, but then i somehow need to have access to the address components in English to put those into the database.

In short:
I need the built-in Google address placeholder to be in the user's language
I need address values in English only to put into my database.  How should I go about doing this?

The code:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;

 var componentFormOrig = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

 var componentToIdOrig = {
  street_number: 'id_original_address',
  route: 'id_original_address',
  locality: 'id_original_city',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'id_original_state',
  country: 'id_original_country',
  postal_code: 'id_zip_code'
};



function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('id_original_address'));

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress.bind(null, autocomplete, componentFormOrig, componentToIdOrig));


}

function fillInAddress(autocompleteObj, componentForm, componentToId) {
console.log(autocompleteObj);
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocompleteObj.getPlace();

    for (var item in componentToId) {
      console.log(item);
      document.getElementById(componentToId[item]).value = '';
      document.getElementById(componentToId[item]).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details,
    // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
    var fullAddress = [];
    console.log("address_components");
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      console.log(place.address_components[i]);
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      console.log("addressType=" + addressType);
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        console.log("val=" + val);
        document.getElementById(componentToId[addressType]).value = val;
      }
      if (addressType == "street_number") {
        fullAddress[0] = val;
      } else if (addressType == "route") {
        fullAddress[1] = val;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById(componentToId['street_number']).value = fullAddress.join(" ");
    if (document.getElementById(componentToId['street_number']).value !== "") {
      document.getElementById(componentToIdOrig['street_number']).disabled = false;
    }
  }

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
                {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
}

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=---&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```